# Xamarin UITabbar multi bar items

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitabbar

I am using Xamarin Studio 6.0
I have created a TabBar and have added multi items to it, the items cover each others. 
This is the code and screenshot:

```
        var items = new UITabBarItem[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {   

            var tabBarItem = new UITabBarItem("TAB ITEM"+i, null, i);
            items[i] = tabBarItem;
        }

        TabLanguageBar.Items = items;
        TabLanguageBar.ItemSpacing = 10;
        TabLanguageBar.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("tab bar button item slected");

        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the way a `UITabBar` works, you will need to either display a subset of them at one time or alter your UI design.

> A tab bar displays all of its tabs **onscreen at once**, using the itemPositioning property to determine how to position items in the available space.
>
> If you have **more items than can fit in the available space, display only a subset of them** and let the user select which tabs are displayed. The beginCustomizingItems: method displays an interface for selecting which tab bar items to display.

Ref: [UITabBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/index.html)